# A Panel To Block a View Android

Tags: android, controls, panel, block

Greetings!

I'm building an app that requires internet use and a whole tab doesn't work without it.  I would like it so that when they select the tab it checks if there is internet and if there isn't then a panel slide (or appears) over the controls so that nothing can be done until an connection to the internet is established.  How could I achieve this?

Thanks
-Mitchell

Answer (score 0):

I think covering the controls would look weird since it would make it look like an empty useless tab.  I would say there are two better ways of doing this.  The first is when the tab gains focus you can disable or enable all the controls based on the detection of a network connection.  The other would be to add or remove the whole tab based on the detection of the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Consider implementing an non-cancelable ProgressDialog (using STYLE_SPINNER) with an AsyncTask that monitors for internet connectivity. Upon connectivity identified, then cancel the ProgressDialog. You may want to provide a timeout also which brings up a relevant error message.

Comment: Once the user clicked on that tab, they would have to wait for an internet connection.  What happens when they are on a plane?  Should that go on forever?

Comment: Basically, I want a pane to come up over the controls until they get an internet connection.  So yes, if they were on a plane, it would stay there until the connected to the internet.  Trust me, they won't be using this application on a plane anyway.